# How can I get the link of an image from inside the tag in XML java

Tags: java, html, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I am trying to read an XML file and store the value between the tags as a String. But for one tag `<picture url="https://cloudstor.aarnet.edu.au/plus/s/62e0uExNviPanZE/download"/>`

I need to get the URL of the image and store it so that I can use it in future.

I used

```
File stocks = new File("gui.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(stocks);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println("root of xml file" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("billboard");
        System.out.println("==========================");
        Node node = nodes.item(0);
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element element = (Element) node;
             //message = getValue("message", element);
             information = getValue("information", element).trim();
            String picture = getValue("picture url=", element);
        } 
private static String getValue(String tag, Element element) {
    NodeList nodes = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();
    Node node = (Node) nodes.item(0);
    return node.getNodeValue();
}
```

This would work for getting information out of normal tags, such as the information tag here. any idea how can I make it work for the picture tag.

```html
<billboard class="nodarken">

              <information>
                     Billboard with an information tag and nothing else. Note that the text is word-wrapped. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs.
              </information>
              <picture url="https://cloudstor.aarnet.edu.au/plus/s/62e0uExNviPanZE/download"/>

       </billboard>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**use** `<link><![CDATA[ your url goes here ]]></link>` **this format**

```html
<billboard class="nodarken">

              <information>
                     Billboard with an information tag and nothing else. Note that the text is word-wrapped. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs.
              </information>
              <picture><![CDATA[ https://cloudstor.aarnet.edu.au/plus/s/62e0uExNviPanZE/download"]]></picture>


       </billboard>
```

Comment: I am reading the XML file, I can't physically change the file like that

Comment: dont change the file just change the syntax of ur image and try it may work

Comment: Hey venkat, by any chance you can explain this to me with an example code? I can't find the resource to do this anywhere please? Thanks :)